# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I'm rather new so bear with me. Im using the babel loader in my webpack config for a react app. However, it doesn't seem to want to process CSS. When I remove the CSS file from my project, it works fine. This is the error im getting

```
ERROR in ./public/App.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> #root, #window, body{
|   min-height: 100vh;
|   position: relative
 @ ./src/app/App.js 2:0-30
 @ ./src/index.js 3:0-28 4:50-53
```

This is what my webpack looks like

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

My entry point index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And lastly my App.js to which index.js refers to

```
import '../../public/App.css'
import React from "react";
import { Menu, Navbar } from '../components';

// Menu app designed for mobile menu viewing. No ordering functionality.

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div id='window'>
      Hello im 
      <Menu />
      <Navbar/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: The error message is correct, you do in fact not have a CSS loader

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/

Answer (score 1):

Babel is intended to only process JavaScript files, so as the error message suggests, you will need to add a CSS loader.

If you look at the Webpack documentation:

- https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/
- https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/

You'll find out that in fact you need at least two loaders to process your css.

So here's what you should do:

- Install style loader:

```
npm install style-loader
```

- Install css loader

```
npm install css-loader
```

- Update your Webpack configuration by adding a new value to your rules array, which will become:

```js
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
  },
],
```

This should fix the error.